# Swift: Saving file with special characters

Tags: swift, character-encoding

I have written the following small function to load a file from a server and saved it to the app documents folder.
This func works fine. Until the filename on the server contains a German "Umlaut" like äöüß

The source file is like:
http:// scripts.myserver.org/aw/database/Bärbel.json
and the destination file looks like:
/Users/michael/.../Documents/Ba%CC%88rbel.json

how do I convert the URL to the right format? It looks again as a big problem for me with an easy solution I'm unable to find... :-(

```
func downloadFile (fileOnServer: String, fileOnDevice: URL) async throws {
       
        guard let dataURL = URL(string: fileOnServer) else { throw URLError.badURL
        }
        let (dataTempFileUrl, _) = try await URLSession.shared.download(from: dataURL)
        let urlData = try Data(contentsOf: dataTempFileUrl)
        try urlData.write(to: fileOnDevice)
        
    }
```

A little bit further trial and error.
the guard statement throws a "BadURL" on fileOnServer which is a string with "http:// scripts.myserver.org/aw/database/Bärbel.json"
So maybe my problem isn't the write part, it's the source string is the problem...

Comment: It seems your issue is not the percent encoding. Please add a [mre]. And please add the error you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:
Changing the function from

```
func downloadFile (fileOnServer: String, fileOnDevice: URL) async throws {
```

to

```
func downloadFile (fileOnServer: URL, fileOnDevice: URL) async throws {
```

complete code:

```
func downloadFile (fileOnServer: URL, fileOnDevice: URL) async throws {
      
        guard let dataURL = URL(string: fileOnServer) else { throw URLError.badURL
        }
        let (dataTempFileUrl, _) = try await URLSession.shared.download(from: dataURL)
        let urlData = try Data(contentsOf: dataTempFileUrl)
        try urlData.write(to: fileOnDevice)
        
    }
```

and preparing the parameter fileOnServer as this:

```
 let url : String = serverDirectory+listOfCategories[index].lowercased()+".json"
                let urlStr : String = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
                let convertedURL : URL = URL(string: urlStr)!
```